# Intellisense not working in VS Code on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

I am running VS Code version 1.17.2 on Ubuntu 16.0.4 on a VMware Player VM in Windows 10. I installed the C++ extension for VS Code. When installing the extension there was a message to say that the extension installed OK but afterwards there was a lot of repeated messages saying something like "failed to update database".

When I type something which is invalid syntax there is no red squiggle and if I press Ctl-Space it just shows "Loading..." but nothing comes. The red flame icon on the status bar shows and I see "Updating Intellisense..." when I hover the mouse over but the icon doesn't ever seem to go away.

If I #include a non existent header, there is no green squiggle but if I save the file, exit VS Code and reopen, them the green squiggle shows on the header but there is no light bulb showing in the left margin.

Comment: have you added the correct path for the bin folder so that the intellisense can work see the [Official Docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md)

Comment: @warl0ck - which part of the linked documentation are you referring to? I have set the path to the executable of my program and VS Code is picking up the path to gdb from the system path as debugging is working.

Answer (score 12):

I had exactly the same problem. I've been playing around with settings and disabling/enabling the extension. Finally got it working with setting the followings then disabling/enabling the extension (reload VS code after both of them):

```
"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled",
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
"C_Cpp.loggingLevel": "Information"
```

Also you can play around with "Reset IntelliSense Database" command, I ran it a couple of times, that might have helped too.
I suspect the intelliSenseEngine setting was the one that made the trick.

**Edit**
This doesn't enable all features, e.g. wrong include markers and "go to definition" works for includes, but code completion doesn't.

Comment: Its working a bit better for me now. For me the red squiggles only show up only in response to compile errors, not before - is that what you observed? It doesn't seem make a difference whether C_Cpp.errorSquiggles is enabled or not. The auto completion is partially working, it does keywork completion but doesn't give me all the methods available for an object for example.

Comment: Yes, it's the same here. Also ctrl+click on included headers and include existence marking works, but full IntelliSense doesn't. :(

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem, running ElementaryOS on VirtualBox. As per this comment (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/756#issuecomment-303513360) I changed my settings to

```
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"
```

And things seems to be working again.

Answer (score 0):

I am running VS Code 1.19.2 with C/C++ IntelliSense 0.15.0 (Microsoft) on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running as a Virtualbox VM (Windows 10 host). All x64 OS's.

In my case the symptom is a recurrent flaming icon in the bottom status bar hinting "Updating IntelliSense..." that seems related to a hung process.
A couple of "Microsoft.VSCod" processes doesn't use CPU...
Hovering over code just hints "Loading...".

After changing "C_Cpp.loggingLevel" to "Information" to analyze log on the Output windows (as requested in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1291 thread) didn't show anything useful... but symptom dissapeared most of the time.

After changing "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine" to "Tag Parser" things went much better. The flaming icon disappeared and definition are available all the time.