# VSCode tip box while typing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I'm pretty new to programming. As I go along with my course's videos, I see that when he is programming on a script on VSCode, he has that tip box that appears after everything he types, for example, he just typed "  if(Input.GetkeyDown(KeyCode.  " after that last dot, his VSCode gave him options to what write next. Every time it does that. But mine doesn't, and without that I won't really be able to learn by myself just playing around.

Another issue I have is that it doesn't autocorrect capital/small letters unless I have already used the same function in that script, then it'll show me the proper way to type it if I press 'tab'.

I'm currently using VSCode on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The 'tip box' is called IntelliSense.  I found this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027720/intellisense-not-working-in-vs-code-on-ubuntu

Comment: Yeah I have the C# Intellisense istalled on my VSCode.. - but I can't really find where to change its settings...